# php(exec) - how do I add a new line to a generated log file?

Tags: php, bash, pipe

Consider:

```
exec("php gmail-smtp.php >> basic-email-template/debug-mailer.log");
```

I want to log file messages to start on a new line. But I cannot find relevant information about Bash pipes.

Comment: Pipes? You'll need to append data (like you're doing with `>>`) - and check if your logger is writing each log entry as a single line, nothing more.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo ? that's exactly what I'm doing. And I've 1 continues line of log file.

Comment: So that's because your logger `gmail-smtp.php` is writing log entries as a single line (without line-break delimiter). Check that first

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo well, what an oversight, but since that's the answer please make it as one and I'll accept.

Comment: Agreed. Updated, thank you.

Comment: Why are you using `exec()` to run another PHP script? Just `ob_start(); require "script.php"; file_put_contents("file.log", ob_get_clean(), FILE_APPEND);` could work as well.

Comment: @Jack I want to run it in background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could lie inside your log file. I.e., you're using `>>` correctly.

The single line in the result file could be because your logger `gmail-smtp.php` is writing log entries as a single line (without a line-break delimiter). Check that first.

Comment: Re *"you're using >> correctly"*: Do you mean *"you're using >>* ***incorrectly"***?

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you the right answer according the way you do it, but just do this:

```
file_put_contents('basic-email-template/debug-mailer.log', "\n", FILE_APPEND)
```

Comment: Point is not logging, but running php in background.